# Keyboard shortcut for adding the current webpage to Favourites in IE8?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

What is quickest keyboard shortcut to add a page to your favourites, using Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
For a complete list of favorites, visit [Microsoft's Help & How-to​](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Internet-Explorer-keyboard-shortcuts).

*Note: not case sensitive*